# Excel - across and down matches

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with two sheets in it, the first looks like this:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
 Last Name | First Name | 1-Jan | 2-Jan | 3-Jan | 4-Jan | (continues on like this)
 --------------------------------------------------------
 SMITH     | John       |    1  |    1  |       |       |
 --------------------------------------------------------
 BOND      | James      |       |       |    1  |    1  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Second sheet

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
                        |   January     | February      | (continues on etc)  
 --------------------------------------------------------
 Last Name | First Name | From  | To    | From  | To    | 
 --------------------------------------------------------
 SMITH     | John       |1/1/18 | 2/2/18|       |       |
 --------------------------------------------------------
 BOND      | James      |3/1/18 |4/1/18 |       |       |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

This is a leave sheet and basically the user inputs on the first sheet a '1' in the day where they are taking leave. This is then automatically updated in the second sheet to reflect the inclusive dates of their leave for each month.

So in the first example, user enters 1 in 1-Jan and 2-Jan, this updates second sheet with leave for that employee from 1/1/18 to 2/1/18.

So far, I'm successful in being able to detect when a 1 is entered it grabs the name and date details, I've been using a msgbox to verify that I'm getting the right data.

The problem I'm having is that's as far as I can get, I can't work out how to search the second sheet to find the dates and update accordingly.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim KeyCells As Range
     ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
     ' cause an alert when they are changed.
     Set KeyCells = Range("D6:OI53")
     If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
         Is Nothing Then
         ' If cell changed, do the below '
         ' Get name '
         Dim lastName As String
         Dim firstName As String
         lastName = ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Cells.Row, 1).Value
         firstName = ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Cells.Row, 2).Value
    'Get date '
    Dim leaveDate As String
    leaveDate = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Target.Cells.Column).Value
    ' Test lastname, firstname, date '
    UpdateMonthlyLeave lastName, firstName, leaveDate
     End If
 End Sub

 Sub UpdateMonthlyLeave(lastName As String, firstName As String, leaveDate As String)
    MsgBox lastName & " " & firstName & " " & leaveDate
    ' Find employee on monthly leave sheet '

 End Sub
```

Comment: what happens when james bond has leave on 6/1/18 - 8/1/18? Does it take on a new line with the person's name repeated? Is your macro firing every time a single cell is altered within the sheet 1 data entry range, before the user has entered their consecutive dates? In its current form, my gut feeling is that a worksheet change event is not the way to go. Rather an update/submit leave button with associated sub or even a Form. Looks like you started on that below but have it tied to the change event.

Comment: Or use the If target.count > statement in the top part to determine when to fire (though i don't think this is viable as you don't know how many Xs they may be entering, only the range of possible counts.)

Comment: @QHarr agree - I've inherited this sheet and am not 100% clear on that, assume that a new line is added with the leave for that same month. The macro fires when a 1 is entered but yes - does not wait for a second 1 to be entered.

Comment: Is the month name on sheet 2 a formatted date?  i.e. Does it hold the value `01/01/2018` and formatted as `mmmm` to show just the month name... or is it a text string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This UDF will return a list of start OR end dates. Just make you you select Wrap Text for the columns in sheet 2. I think one advantage may be Excel would only update the cell with the formula if the ranges it specifies are changed.

Perhaps the code could be simplified further, but unfortunately you will have to enter the formula for each cell in sheet2.

```
Option Explicit
' ShowStartMonth: True If we need to return the start date of the holidays
' MonthRange: The WHOLE Column range of the Month
' RowRange: The Range of the person's row but only the holiday columns, not the name columns
' MonthNameRow: The entire row of where the Month name is
Public Function GetHoliday(ShowStartMonth As Boolean, iMonth As Integer, RowRange As Range, MonthNameRow As Range) As String

    Dim MonthRange As Range
    Set MonthRange = GetMonthRange(iMonth, MonthNameRow)

    'Init variables
    '   Get the cells for the current month
    Dim rRow As Range
    Set rRow = Intersect(RowRange, RowRange.Worksheet.UsedRange, MonthRange)


    Dim IsCurrentCellHoliday As Boolean
    Dim IsLastCellHoliday As Boolean
    Dim IsStartHolidayContinuation As Boolean

    ' If First Day of month is a holiday and last day of last month is a holiday then
    ' Holiday is continuation
    IsStartHolidayContinuation = (rRow.Cells(1).Value = 1) And (rRow.Cells(1).Offset(0, -1).Value = 1)
    IsLastCellHoliday = (rRow.Cells(1).Value = 1)

    ' These will hold the dates for start or end of a holiday
    Dim StartDays() As String
    Dim EndDays() As String
    ReDim StartDays(0 To 255)
    ReDim EndDays(0 To 255)

    Dim SDIndex As Integer  ' Index of the start day array
    Dim EDIndex As Integer  ' Index of the end day array

    ' If Start of month is start of a new holiday then set it
    If (IsLastCellHoliday And Not IsStartHolidayContinuation) Then StartDays(0) = GetMonthName(rRow.Cells(1), MonthNameRow)

    ' If start of month is a holiday then set index to the second "StartHoliday" line
    SDIndex = IIf(IsStartHolidayContinuation Or IsLastCellHoliday, 1, 0) ' Keep first row Empty if start of month is holiday
    EDIndex = 0


    ' Loop through all cells in the month for the person
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = SDIndex + 1 To rRow.Columns.Count
        Dim rCell As Range
        Set rCell = rRow.Cells(i)

        IsCurrentCellHoliday = rCell.Value = 1  'Check if current cell is a holiday

        ' If the current cell is different to the last cell then we need to do something
        If IsCurrentCellHoliday <> IsLastCellHoliday Then
            If IsCurrentCellHoliday Then

                StartDays(SDIndex) = GetMonthName(rCell, MonthNameRow)
                SDIndex = SDIndex + 1

                ' Check if the first day of the next month is a holiday, if not then today is the last day
                If rCell.Column = MonthRange.Columns(MonthRange.Columns.Count).Column And rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> 1 Then
                    EndDays(EDIndex) = GetMonthName(rRow.Cells(i), MonthNameRow)
                    EDIndex = EDIndex + 1
                End If
            Else
                EndDays(EDIndex) = GetMonthName(rRow.Cells(i - 1), MonthNameRow)
                EDIndex = EDIndex + 1
            End If
        End If
        IsLastCellHoliday = IsCurrentCellHoliday
    Next

    Dim ReturnStrings() As String
    Dim ReturnIndex As Integer

    If (ShowStartMonth) Then
        ReturnStrings = StartDays
        ReturnIndex = SDIndex
    Else
        ReturnStrings = EndDays
        ReturnIndex = EDIndex
    End If

    Dim returnString As String
    returnString = IIf(Len(ReturnStrings(0)) = 0, " - ", ReturnStrings(0))

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = LBound(ReturnStrings) + 1 To ReturnIndex - 1
        returnString = returnString & vbNewLine & ReturnStrings(j)
    Next

    GetHoliday = returnString
End Function

Private Function GetMonthName(cell As Range, MonthRow As Range) As String
    Dim rMonth As Range
    Set rMonth = Intersect(cell.EntireColumn, MonthRow.EntireRow)
End Function

Public Function GetMonthRange(iMonth As Integer, MonthNameRow As Range) As Range

    Set MonthNameRow = Intersect(MonthNameRow.EntireRow, MonthNameRow.Worksheet.UsedRange)

    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range

    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In MonthNameRow.Cells
        If IsDate(rCell.Value) Then
            If month(CDate(rCell.Value)) = iMonth Then
                If startCell Is Nothing Then
                 Set startCell = rCell
                ElseIf rCell.Column < startCell.Column Then
                    Set startCell = rCell
                End If

                If endCell Is Nothing Then
                 Set endCell = rCell
                ElseIf rCell.Column > endCell.Column Then
                    Set endCell = rCell
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set GetMonthRange = Range(startCell.Address & ":" & endCell.Address).EntireColumn
    Dim sAddress As String
    sAddress = GetMonthRange.Address
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this - just wanted to clarify your instructions - MonthRange (Sheet1 A3:A30 ) RowRange (Sheet1 B3:B30) MonthNameRow (Sheet2 A3) ?

Comment: @hylian You're welcome. I have updated the functions so instead of `MonthRange`, set `iMonth` as the number of the month. Jan is 1, Feb is 2, etc.

`RowRange` will be for the person's row, for example, assuming Jan-1 is in B3 and Dec-31 in Z3 then `Sheet1!B3:Z3`.

`MonthNameRow` is the entire row the Month name resides on in sheet 1

Comment: Hi @BrownishMonster , I'm still having issues with this, I've uploaded it to Dropbox below. Can you please take a look? Happy to pay you for your time, I'm just getting a #value error and I've tried to trace it through to work out where it is. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwz91aqgzq1laen/Leave%202018-redacted.xlsm?dl=0